# Apache Httpd - endpoint authorization with load balancing

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, authentication, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Apache Httpd is being used as a load balancer between two end point servers. Each server has it's own HTTP authentication. The goal is to have the end point authentication passed to the user, the user enters their credentials, and authentication is passed back to the end point server.

When I set up Apache as a reverse proxy, the authentication is passed without a problem. When I go to localhost, I get prompted for credentials, I enter them, and then the site works fine. Here is my configuration for reverse proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://serv123:27001/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://serv123:27001/"
    <Location "/">  
        SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On 
    </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

But, when I add load balancing, it seems that proxy-chain-auth isn't configured correctly. When I enter the credentials, I immediately get prompted again as if they weren't entered correctly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass "/" "balancer://mycluster/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://mycluster/"

    <Location "/">  
        SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On 
    </Location>

    <Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
        BalancerMember "http://serv123:27001/"
        BalancerMember "http://serv456:27001/"
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried `<Location "balancer://mycluster">` and `<Location "balancer://mycluster/">` with no success. Does anyone know the proper way to pass authentication through Apache Httpd with load balancing?

Comment: is your cookie set correctly? if I understand it correctly, the backends are setting those? do they use their own (private) fqdn as cookie domain or the public one?

Comment: did you find the root of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In this balancing construct each request may (and most likely will) be answered by the other server, so the browser cookie containing the sessionid is overwritten on every request-login-sequence and the session seems to be always invalid.

There are various ways to work around this problem:

- If using `stickysessions` is an option, you could use this simple system to make sure users are always handled by the same server (as long as it is alive and the cookie is valid). The downside is: when the server dies the user has to login again.
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#stickyness
- If loosing a session is totally out of the question, you should make sure the applications on both servers always know about all logins/sessions. So you could use a database backend (or even save this information to a central storage as files) to save them and validate every request against those db-saved-sessions. Downside is switching server on every other request kills server-side caching efficiency.
- combine both attempts to allow efficient caching: subsequent requests are always handled by the same server (sticky sessions) and when one server fails the other takes over and reconstructs the session from the session backend. Caching has to be redone at this point as long as you don't use a shared memcached or similar approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Phillip. Considering your reply, I limited the balance cluster to only one member and tried authentication. With only one member, I still have the same issue.

Although I think you're correct that I will run into an invalid session issue due to the nature of balancing, I think that my first roadblock is because the auth info isn't being sent to the endpoint server.